# (Laravel) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing some error that saying `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'`

This is my views in Laravel

```
               @for($i = 0;$i < 6;$i++)
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{date("Y", strtotime($data[$i]->date))}}</td>
                    <td>{{date("M", strtotime($data[$i]->date))}}</td>
                    <td>{{$data[$i]->total}}</td>
                    <td>{{$st[$i]}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bt[$i]}}</td>

                    @if({{$ftm[$i]}}==null)
                        <td></td>
                    @elseif({{$ftm[$i]}}!=null)
                        <td>{{$ftm[$i]}}</td>
                    @endif

                    <td>{{$pe[$i]}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endfor
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: which line does it say?

Comment: @BenLonsdale Good question +1. Anyway, I found where the error is without that: look at the `@if({{$ftm[$i]}}==null)` line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You dont need to add `{{ }}` when your variable is in a `@if` statement.

Replace:

```
@if({{$ftm[$i]}}==null)
     <td></td>
@elseif({{$ftm[$i]}}!=null)
     <td>{{$ftm[$i]}}</td>
@endif
```

With:

```
@if($ftm[$i]==null)
    <td></td>
@elseif($ftm[$i]!=null)
    <td>{{$ftm[$i]}}</td>
@endif
```